# AngularJS file upload, Express and node-postgres (pg)

Tags: angularjs, express, file-upload, node-postgres

Got a component in AngularJS (porting soon to Angular 7) for updating a user profile that invokes an AngularJS service method to perform a PUT to /api/user/:id.

Want to add a small photo (<100K) to send in the same PUT with the other fields then handle the request like this in the controller...

```
// route: PUT /api/user/:id
import db from '../../utils/db';

export async function upsert(req, res) {
  const { id, name, phone, email, photo } = req.body;
  // users.photo in PostgreSQL has datatype of bytea
  const sql = `UPDATE users SET name = $2, phone = $3, email = $4, photo = $5) WHERE id = $1 RETURNING id, name, phone, email, photo;`;
  const { rows } = db.query(sql, [id, name, phone, email, photo];
  return res.status(200).send(rows);
}
```

Is there a clean way to encode the image client-side so it can be included in the JSON the AngularJS service PUTs? Other solutions I found seem like overkill for this use-case - requiring the image upload to be handled very differently from the other fields.

Comment: You can use "data URIs" but you generally want to keep those somewhat small (<32KB). It *may* work at larger sizes, depending on the browser.

Comment: Yeah, seems like this would be a fit. Wondering if I'm boxing myself into a corner and whether I should just "bite the bullet" and implement something like ng-file-upload in combination with formidable, busboy, or multer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up biting the bullet - creating a separate table for files along with its own API using **formidable** and **node-postgres**. In case this helps anyone else, here's how it turned out.

PostgreSQL data definition...

```
-- DROP SEQUENCE public.files_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS public.files_seq;

-- DROP TABLE public.files;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.files (
  _id integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('files_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(512) NOT NULL,
  type character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  data bytea
);

-- DROP INDEX public.users_first_name;
CREATE INDEX files_name ON public.files USING btree (name);
```

Controller for Express...

```
import stream from 'stream';
import fs from 'fs';
import { IncomingForm } from 'formidable';
import db from '../../utils/db';

// Returns list of images
export async function index(req, res) {
  const { rows } = await db.query('SELECT _id, name, type FROM files ORDER BY name;', []);
  return res.send(rows);
}

// Uploads a single file
export async function upload(req, res) {
  let _id;
  new IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(Array.isArray(files)) throw new Error('Only one file can be uploaded at a time');
    const { name, type, path } = files.file;
    fs.readFile(path, 'hex', async(err, fileData) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      fileData = `\\x${fileData}`;
      const sql = 'INSERT INTO files (name, type, data) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING _id;';
      const { rows } = await db.query(sql, [name, type, fileData]);
      _id = rows[0]._id;
      res.send({ id: _id });
      // console.log(`Uploaded ${name} to ${path} and inserted into database (ID = ${_id})`);
      // No need to delete the file uploaded as Heroku has an ephemeral file system
    });
  });
}

// Downloads a file by its _id
export async function download(req, res) {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  const sql = 'SELECT _id, name, type, data FROM files WHERE _id = $1;';
  const { rows } = await db.query(sql, [_id]);
  const file = rows[0];
  const fileContents = Buffer.from(file.data, 'base64');
  const readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  readStream.end(fileContents);
  res.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${file.name}`);
  res.set('Content-Type', file.type);
  readStream.pipe(res);
  return rows[0];
}

// Deletes a file from the database (admin-only)
export async function destroy(req, res) {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  const sql = 'DELETE FROM files WHERE _id = $1;';
  await db.query(sql, [_id]);
  res.status(204).send({ message: `File ${_id} deleted.`});
}
```

On the client side, I'm using **ng-file-upload** with AngularJS.

Here's the relevant part of the view (in pug for brevity)...

```
.form-group.col-md-6
  label(for='photo') Teacher photo
  input.form-control(ngf-select='$ctrl.uploadPhoto($file)', type='file', id='photo', name='photo', ng-model='$ctrl.user.photo', ngf-pattern="'image/*'", ngf-accept="'image/*'", ngf-max-size='100KB', ngf-min-height='276', ngf-max-height='276', ngf-min-width='236', ngf-max-width='236', ngf-resize='{width: 236, height: 276}', ngf-model-invalid='errorFile')
  ng-messages.help-block.has-error(for='form.photo.$error', ng-show='form.photo.$dirty || form.$submitted', role='alert')
    ng-message(when='maxSize') Please select a photo that is less than 100K.
    ng-message(when='minHeight,maxHeight,minWidth,maxWidth') The image must be 236 x 276 pixels.
  span(ng-if='$ctrl.user.imageId')
    img(ng-src='/api/file/{{ $ctrl.user.imageId }}' alt="Photo of Teacher")
```

and method in its controller...

```
  uploadPhoto(file) {
    if(file) {
      this.uploadService.upload({
        url: '/api/file/upload',
        data: { file }
      })
        .then(response => {
          this.user.imageId = response.data.id;
        }, response => {
          if(response.status > 0) console.log(`${response.status}: ${response.data}`);
        }, evt => {
          // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
          this.uploadProgress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total, 10));
        });
    }
  }
```